# OpenGL: Access violation when using glTransformFeedbackVaryings and glDrawElements

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

My shader works fine and now I want to add transform feedback during the same render pass by simply specifying one additional out variable in my geometry shader `out vec3 vertexPosition`.

However when I add
`glTransformFeedbackVaryings(_programHandle, _numVaryings, _varyings, _bufferMode);`

then my drawCall:

`glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, meshRenderable._mesh->_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);`

results in an access violation.

```
Exception thrown at 0x000000005851968A (atio6axx.dll) in Shady.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000014.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.`
```

Without `glTransformFeedbackVaryings` the `glDrawElements` call works fine. The shader consists of a vertex shader, a geometry shader (which transforms each triangle into 4 triangles) and a fragment shader.

Why would specifying the transformFeedback varyings cause an access violation? I did not even use `glGetBufferSubData` yet and neither did create a buffer for TF and I assume the bound VAO is fine otherwise I would not get a corect draw call without the `glTransformFeedbackVaryings`!

I used `glGetString` to verify that `EXT_transform_feedback` is supported and the EXT shows up and also validated the shader which returned `Validation successful`.

Update: The reason drawElements caused an access violation was likely because I did not specify all TF elements (no buffer, no TF object, no `glBindBufferBase`). I assumed if I never call `glBeginTransformFeedback` this would not cause any side effects as no transform feedback would be active. However, this seems to be a wrong assumption. It would be very nice if someone could explain if it is valid to specify varyings without setting up the other TF objects and why OpenGL requires a proper setup for TF even if TF is never enabled.

Comment: Your "solution" seems coincidental. It's more likely that you are passing in an invalid pointer to an OpenGL function, and that it only causes a failure later on, under specific circumstances. Please create a [mcve].